# Not able to connect an external monitor

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am new to ubuntu and I am facing this behavior and don't know what to do. I would appreciate any help.

I am trying to connect external monitor via VGA(I tried even via HDMI,but no use) but not able to connect external monitor in my laptop.  I don`t see any option in system settings or any where. I guess my laptop is not detecting external monitor.

When I give xrandar while external monitor is connected, I am getting following error

```
 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
 Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1368 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
 default connected 1368x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768        0.0
   1368x768        0.0*
```

I am stuck in this issue.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and KDE plasma desktop and my laptop model is DELL latitude E5530.

Can somebody create some diagnoses and give some possible solution, please?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546322/not-able-to-connect-an-external-monitor)

Answer (score 1):

At last I found the way. Problem is with "nomodeset" in grub file(/etc/default/grub),

here GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" here nomodeset shall not be there which is causing the problem.
I have changed that line to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and I did "sudo update-grub" and rebooted the machine, it started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like issue with the resolution factor.. So first you need to find the the exact monitors and resolution by using the following command:

xrandr -q

Once you got the output, take the current value of your monitor resolution and register the new mode using this command.

```
xrandr --addmode <your_connection_type> "preferred resolution"
```

Hope this helps..